# Updating Magento SOAP V1 api additional attributes

Tags: php, api, magento, soap, attributes

Morning all! I'm attempting to target a specific product with Magento's SOAP V1 API, and change the value of one of its additional attributes. In the Magento Docs, it calls for an associative array named 'single_data'.

I've tried following a few other overflow questions, but I cannot seem to piece together an array to update one of its attributes. Has someone successfully done this that could help? Any support is much appreciated!

Comment: I've been struggling with this for a few days, but I just solved it, just in case anyone ever finds this.
Within your catalog_product.update array, add the line: `'additional_attributes' => array( 'single_data' => array('suppliersku' => $suppliersku))`
If you need to update multiple attributes, change out 'single_data' to 'multi_data' and fiddle around with the attributes inside of that.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You should post that an an answer and accept it - it may help others in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been struggling with this for a few days, but I just solved it, just in case anyone ever finds this. Within your catalog_product.update array, add the line:

`'additional_attributes' => array( 'single_data' => array('suppliersku' => $suppliersku))`

If you need to update multiple attributes, change out 'single_data' to 'multi_data' and fiddle around with the attributes inside of that